# how to set the text in <a> tag to url after clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

My HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/styles.css" />
    <title>MrSrv7</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="slideContainer"></div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Script is

```
var slides = ["slide 1", "slide 2", "slide 3", "slide 4", "slide 5"]
var str = '<ul>'

slides.map((slide, index)=> {

  str += "<li> <a href='?'>"+ slide + '</a> </li>'; // I need to set the href
attribute so that whatever link is clicked, the text in it must be appended 
URL bar.
  console.log(index)
}); 

str += '</ul>';
document.getElementById("slideContainer").innerHTML = str;
```

For Eg : if the user is clicking the slide1 link then the URL must be http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html#slide1

if the user is clicking the slide5 link then the URL must be http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html#slide5

Comment: Can you clarify a little more?

Comment: you need to use some DOM methods to do that

Comment: Do you want to append `slide` variable to the end of the URL in the `href` attribute within the map function?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Please clarify on what you want to do and dont just paste your code

Comment: @Akash i have edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var slides = ["slide 1", "slide 2", "slide 3", "slide 4", "slide 5"]

var str = '<ul>'


slides.map((slide, index)=> {

  str += "<li> <a href='"+ "#" + slide.replace(" ", "") + "' >"+ slide + '</a> </li>';
  console.log(index)
}); 

str += '</ul>';
document.getElementById("slideContainer").innerHTML = str;
```

this is what you wanted to do?

Comment: Almost! but this is adding % to the URL bar. Like " http://127.0.0.1:5500/slide%205 " but want like http://127.0.0.1:5500/#slide5

Comment: i add .replace() and + "#"

now its ok?

Comment: wow, exactly what i was looking for! Thank You So Much :)

Answer (score 2):

I hope the following is useful for you.

```
var slides = [
  { link: 'https://www.google.com.tr/', title: 'Google' },
  { link: 'https://www.google.com.tr/', title: 'Google' },
  { link: 'https://www.google.com.tr/', title: 'Google' }
]

function getLinkItem(link, title) {
  var el =  document.createElement("li")
  el.innerHTML = "<a href='" + link + "'>" + title + "</a>";

  return el
}

for(var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  var dataItem = slides[i];
  var htmlItem = getLinkItem(dataItem.link, dataItem.title);

  document.getElementById('link-list').appendChild(htmlItem)
}
```

Example here: https://codepen.io/yasgo/pen/QWKWbeE